# How does Siltbreaker, battle point count?

Tags: dota-2

Recently Valve, launched Siltbreaker campaign in Dota 2, Does anyone know how do they count the battle points with the single game?

Answer (score 3):

According to the wiki:

http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Siltbreaker/Act_I#Rewards

You can earn 200 points for each one star, 400 points for each two star, and a Siltbreaker Reward for three stars.

For defeating the final boss: 1 star: 50 points, 2 stars: 100 points, 3 stars: 150 points.

Then there are achievements that you can complete that will earn you somewhere between 250 and 2000 points each.

*edit*:

Also, people with a battlepass level at least 165 will receive 2 Siltbreaker rewards for the three-star rewards.